# Question about Bhabha scattering Feynman Diagram

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

I'm a uni student going into his third year, and thought I might try to read through Griffith's particle physics textbook for the heck of it. I've been trying to become familiar with Feynman diagrams, but there is one that's confusing me. I drew a feynman diagram for Bhaba (electron-positron) scattering, it should be at the bottom of the post. I'm not 100% on the conventions for drawing a feynman diagram, so let's say that time moves to the right here. The bottom in-going and outgoing particles are electrons and the top in-going and outgoing particles are positrons (the "+" part of "e+" didn't show up here for some reason).

My main question is what in the world are the two virtual particles (the one's that aren't photons)? I have placed question marks next to them in the image for convenience.

If we focus on leftmost virtual particle for now, it could in my mind be either an electron or a positron. My reasoning is, if we start by focusing on the in-going electron, we could say that it emitted a virtual photon and a virtual electron. The virtual electron then annihilated with the in-going positron to create our second virtual photon. However, the reverse could just as easily be the case, with our in-going positron emitted a virtual photon and a virtual positron, and our virtual positron annihilating with our in-going electron. But surely it can't be both!

Another thing that's troubling me is that, if we let time move to the right, our virtual particles are moving orthogonal to time. Would this imply that they don't experience any time?

A third thing that i'm confused about here is that there is also the rightmost virtual particle. The arrow is moving in the opposite direction of the leftmost virtual particle. Would this imply that our leftmost and rightmost virtual particles are different? If it does, how are the two different? our electron and positron are clearly different as one is the time-reversed version of the either, but these two virtual particles move orthogonal to time.

Can someone please help me out here?

[image]

Comment: depends on the direction you read them, virtual electrons or posttrons (Virtual means off mass shell, not photon).

Comment: You've drawn the 1-loop diagram to the tree level diagram of this scattering event, any particular reason or just curious about the internal lines? Nothing stops you from drawing the vertical legs slanted. You could even draw the 4 legs vertical or horizontal.

Comment: I'm just curious about the internal lines. Would drawing the internal lines slanted change what the interaction is at all, or is it simply notation? Is my diagram in the post just ambiguous? Sorry if these are really simple questions, I'm just new to all this.

Comment: The only difference is that internal lines are off mass shell, i.e.they carry in the feynman diagram the quantum numbers of a particle but they are off mass shell, i.e. their fouvector when dotted gives a mass different than the mass on the table of particle  physics. This is because only incoming and outgoing particles of the feynman diagram are measurable on mass shell . The internal particles are under the integral which the diagram represents,, their mass appears in the propagator that mathematically represents them,, under the integral.

Comment: the lines are a matter of how you want to read them, slant makes no difference, only difference is the way the arrow points, which defines whether one is talking of a particle( written, flollowing the arrow direction) or an antiparticle (against the arrow direction)